# html5 video bitrate switching

Tags: html, html5-video

we are looking to implement video in to our website, but we want to switch the video bitrate depending on the quality of the viewers internet connection.

- Fits the bandwidth of the server » client connection.
- Fits the width of the player’s display (or, to be precise, is not more than 20% larger).
- Does not result in more than 25% of frames dropped at any time.

Is there a way to do this using HTML5 video?

kind regards,
Daan

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331907/html5-video-detecting-bandwidth might be some answers there for folks who land here

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think so i am looking for a solution to this aswell. As far as i know html5 video only supports progressive video downloading or HLS which can not do multi bitrate streaming.

However using flash instead of html5 video can support multi bitrate streaming. The downside is that your users will need to have Flash installed on their system.

If the user does not have flash fall back to HLS on html5, which is supported on all browsers and devices. (as far as i know).

This is how i am planning to set up my website but i am still confused aswell.

Comment: I have the same dillemma. Youtube seems to be doing this. Try using the html5 player and set the quality to auto: The player will use the best bitrate depending on display size/bandwith.